# C++ use std::greater() in priority_queue and sort

Tags: c++, c++11, object, templates, types

Why the documentation for both cases says the same thing, but they are declared in an opposite way, one uses `greater<int>` while the other uses `greater<int>()`. Could anyone please shed some light on it?

The documentation [priority_queue cpp library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/priority_queue/) says that comp

> can be Comparison object to be used to order the heap. This may be a
>   function pointer or function object

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> minheap;  //works
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>() > minheap; //why fail?
```

The documentation [cpp library sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) says the same thing, that is, comp can either be a function pointer or a function object.

```
sort (numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::greater<int>()); //works
sort (numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::greater<int>); //fail
```

Comment: One is a template argument, the other is a function argument (`<>` is different from `()`).

Comment: But the documentation says that both cases shall be able to use function argument (function object or pointers) , thus greater<int>() shall works for both cases, right? Why does it fail for priority_queue

Comment: Yes, if you pass it to the constructor, not as a template argument. You would specify the type `std::greater<int>` in the template argument and then pass an object of that type `std::greater<int>()` in the constructor arguments.

Comment: I'm surprised no one's mentioned that when used as a type, `std::greater<int>()` isn't just an immediate error, but a valid type denoting a function that returns a `std::greater<int>`. The error you get from the compiler will be when it realizes that function type isn't suitable as a comparator.

Comment: `greater<int>` is a type. `greater<int>()` is a value. When you instantiate template you need a type, when you call a function template you need a value. Note that sort detects types, so you do not have to write `sort<container::iterator_type, std::greater<int>>(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), {})` which will be form similar to `priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>>`

Comment: @MarekR Actually, `greater<int>()` *is* a type. It's just not a type that can be used as a comparison object (see also chris' comment).

Comment: @eerorika greater<int>() is either a type specifier or an expression depending on the used context.:) For example if you will enclose the construction in parentheses then  there will not be an ambiguity.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Well, yes without context it could be either. But in the context of this question, in particular in `priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>() >`, it is a type.

Comment: @eerorika I have appended my answer. See it.:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this declaration

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> minheap;
```

`greater<int>` is a template argument that specifiers a type and corresponds to the type template parameter `class Compare` of the priority_queue

```
template<class T, class Container = vector<T>,
class Compare = less<typename Container::value_type>>
class priority_queue;
```

In this statement

```
sort (numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::greater<int>());
```

there is used the default constructor to create a temporary object of the type `greater<int>`.

`std::greater` is a template structure

```
template<class T = void> struct greater;
```

that is its specialization provides a type.

You can use the template specializations as type specifiers in declarations. For example

```
std::greater<int> obj1;
std::greater<double> obj2;
std::greater<std::string> obj3;
```

In the first case you have to specify the type argument for the corresponding type template parameter.

In the second case you have to specify an object of the type `greater<int>`.

Take into account that if you will try to use the record `std::greater<int>()` as a template argument for the priority_queue then the compiler considers it as a function type specifier that has return type `std::greater<int>` and has no parameters. Because the compiler expects a type specifier as a template argument and not an expression. But specifying such a function type as a type template argument does not make sense for the priority_queue.

To make it more clear rewrite a call of std::sort the following way

```
std::greater<int> obj;
sort (numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), obj );
```

As you see here is `std::greater<int>` is a type specifier for the variable `obj` which is supplied as an argument to the function `std::sort`. The difference between the call above and this call

```
sort (numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::greater<int>());
```

is that in the last case there is created a temporary object of the type `std::greater<int>` like `std::greater<int>()`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::greater<int> comp;

    //  Here is used an already created object of the type std::greater<int> 
    std::sort( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), comp );

    for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    //  Here is used a remporary object of the type std::less<int> 
    std::sort( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), std::less<int>() );

    for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! So, sort() uses the function object, but why the template argument won't work for sort()?

Comment: @coder The std:;sort requires a function object not a type specifier. That is you need provide an expression as an argument. The std::sort already declared the parameter as having some type.

Answer (score 4):

The third template argument for [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) is the *type* of the comparator.

With `greater<int>()` you create an instance (an object) of the `greater<int>` class, and you pass this instance (object) as argument instead of the type `greater<int>`.

For [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) the third function argument is an actual object (or rather, anything that is callable).

---

Regarding the reference you link to, it's a reference of the ***constructor***, not the `std::priority_queue` template itself. Constructor arguments are like function arguments, and are very different from the template arguments.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But the documentation of priority_queue says that function object can be used, why does it fail?

Comment: @coder You're looking at the `std::priority_queue` ***constructor*** reference, where you indeed can pass a callable object like `std::greater<int>()` (or anything else that is callable).

Comment: You are right. However, why does `priority_queue<int, vector<int>> pq(greater<int>()) pq;` declaration fail? Could you please show how to use the `greater<int>()` to construct a priority_queue?

Comment: @coder That definition is simply wrong because you can do something like `int a{0} a;` Do you mean e.g. `priority_queue<int, vector<int>> pq{greater<int>()};`?

Answer (score 0):

In short, when you need to provide type like for template argument, if you provide call of default constructor for that type, eg , default constructed instance, you get compile time error.

Similarly, when you need to provide instance, like for sort function third  argument, if you provide type you get compile time error, and if you provide default constructed instance, it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Simply depending if you need a type (when defining a type) or value (when invoking template function) you need a type or default constructed instance of type respectively.

Note that you can have opposite equivalents of using `greater<int>{}` `greater<int>`. For `sort` compiler deduces types and you can omit type deduction. In case of `priority_queue` you can use C++17 and make compiler deduce types based on constructor arguments. So here is code which looks strange but it compiles:

```
priority_queue a{ greater<int>{}, vector<int>{} };  

int tab[] { 3, 4, 5, 0 };
sort<int*, greater<int>>(tab, tab + 3, {});
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/X4aHIzvOqAlOWGoP